# Lagrange's theorem and convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

Let f:U⊂ $\mathbb{R}^n$--->$\mathbb{R}$  a $C^1$ function  with U being convex and an open set.
Let g: U ⊂  $\mathbb{R}^n$ ---> $\mathbb{R}^m$ (with m smaller than n) an affine application. Let M={x $ \in$ U | g(x)=0  and rank(Jg(x))=m} Let $x_o$ in M and $\lambda $ in $\mathbb{R^m}$ such that  $\bigtriangledown f(x_o)= \lambda   .    \bigtriangledown g(x_o) $. Show that if f is convex, than $x_o$ is an absolute minimum of the function f on M. 
(Note :  the point . represents the scalar product)

I know that if f is convex, than  f(y) ≥ f(x) + f'(x) (y-x) for x,y in U . 
Can anyone help me complete this problem?
thanks.

Comment: You need to proofread. Is $f:U\to\Bbb R$ and $g:U\to\Bbb R^m$? But then your Lagrange multipliers statement is wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin my mistake ! I edited my post. hope this helps

Comment: Still not right. To talk about a function having a maximum/minimum, it must be real-valued, so $f: U\to\Bbb R$, as I said. Next, we don't really write $\nabla g$ when $g$ is vector-valued. But I understand what you mean.

Comment: @TedShifrin many define/use the gradient as the transpose of the Jacobian even for vector valued functions. That isn't uncommon.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes it is in R. Can you help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange multiplier condition tells you that $\nabla f(x_0) = \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i\nabla g_i(x_0)$ is normal (orthogonal) to the affine subspace $M$. This means that $\nabla f(x_0)\cdot (y-x_0) = 0$ for any $y\in M$. Thus, since $f$ is convex, for any $y\in M$ we have $$f(y)\ge f(x_0)+\nabla f(x_0)\cdot (y-x_0) = f(x_0).$$ This means $x_0$ is a global minimum of $f$ on $M$.

Comment: You forgot the multipliers in the sum :D

Comment: @user251257: Oops, sorry! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @TedShifrin , im sorry i do not see why $\nabla f(x_o) $ is normal to the affine subsbace M. and why does this imply that $ \nabla f(x_o) . (y-x_o ) $ for any y in m?

Comment: Because (1) the vectors tangent to $M$ at $x_0$ are orthogonal to *all* $\nabla g_i(x_0)$; and (2) $M$ is a affine subspace (so a linear object, just translated off the origin). Therefore, for any $x,y\in M$, $y-x$ is in the *subspace* $M_0$ (the translate of $M$ to the origin) and therefore orthogonal to all the $\nabla g_i(x_0)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin i understand that all the vectors tangents to M are orthogonal to $\nabla g_i(x_0)$ but how to we know that y-x is Tangent to M? all we know is that y,x is in M.

Comment: Remember that $M$ is an affine linear space, as I said above. This is a translate of a linear subspace.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know i am asking for a lot, but im not sure that i understand what the concept of a affine linear space is and why it is a linear subspace. can you give me more details^

Comment: Your function $g$ is affine linear. With your rank condition, this means $g(x) = Ax-b$ for an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with rank $m$ and a fixed vector $b\in\Bbb R^m$. Setting $g=0$ means we're looking at $M = \{x\in\Bbb R^n: Ax=b\}$. (This is the standard set up of systems of linear equations. The only difference here is that we know that our $m$ linear equations are independent. That's the rank condition.)